# Using flow_from_dataframe what is the correct "value" for y_col

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generator, tf.keras

I am reading in a csv file with pandas, and give the column names stored in `colname`

```
colnames=['file', 'label'] 
# Read data from file 
data = pd.read_csv('./Hand_Annotations_2.csv',names=colnames, header=None)
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
data.head()
```

Then, I use `ImageDataGenerator()` and `flow_fromdataframe()` to get batches of data

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=data,
                                            directory=None, 
                                            x_col=colnames[0], 
                                            y_col=colnames[1],
                                            class_indices=IDmap,
                                            class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=32)
```

But I get an error, as below:

> TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="label" column values
>   must be type string, list or tuple.

But my `y_col` is a string. I get the same error if I just enter `"label"`. It also seems to work with `x_col`.

Can someone point me to my mistake?

Thanks

---

**Solution**

read csv with dtype e.g. str:

```
data = pd.read_csv('./Hand_Annotations_2.csv',dtype=str,names=colnames, header=None)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the code in github for what it is actually being checked, specially [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py#L201). Keras preprocessing is checking that all the values have allowed types (str, list or tuple), so the check is failing, you have to check that all values of the `y_col` column have the right type.

Answer (score 1):

If your labels are integer, set `class_mode='raw'`