# flow_from_dataframe() error: If class_mode="categorical", y_col column values must be type string, list or tuple

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to use `flow_from_dataframe()` to train my model from a .csv in which each image belong to just one category. You can check a sample picture of the .csv [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj0rE.png).

I think `class_mode` should be set to `categorical`, since [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdataframe-method) says the following:

> "categorical": 2D NumPy array of one-hot encoded labels. Supports
>   multi-label output.

The problem is that, although the .csv is read as string, the following error appears when using `categorical`:

```
If class_mode="categorical", y_col="['MEL', 'NV', 'BCC', 'AK', 'BKL', 'DF', 'VASC', 'SCC', 'UNK']" column values must be type string, list or tuple.
```

It works fine when setting `class_mode = 'raw'`, but isn't `categorical` the most appropiate according to the documentation? I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460581/using-flow-from-dataframe-what-is-the-correct-value-for-y-col) solution but doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
    df_train = pd.read_csv('/content/truth.csv',dtype=str)

    train_generator = datagen_train.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = df_train,
        directory = "/content/ISIC_2019_Training_Input",
        x_col = 'image',
        y_col = ['MEL','NV','BCC','AK','BKL','DF','VASC','SCC','UNK'],
        batch_size = 32,
        shuffle = True,
        class_mode = "categorical",
        target_size = (224,224)
    )
```

Thanks in advance!